# Use multiple databases in Django with only one table "django_migrations"

Tags: python, django, django-models

For a project in Django I have to use two databases: **default** and **remote**. I have created `routers.py` and everything works fine.

There was a requirement to create a table on the remote database and I created migration, run it and the table `django_migrations` was created. I want to have only one table `django_migrations`, in the default database.

The relevant part of `routers.py` is here:

```
class MyRouter(object):
     # ...
     def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
         if app_label == 'my_app':
             return db == 'remote'
         return None
```

I run the migration like this:

```
python manage.py migrate my_app --database=remote
```

Now when I do:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I get the following warning:

> You have 1 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): my_app.
>   Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

The tables for `my_app` are created in the `remote` database, and in `django_migrations` inside the `remote` database the migrations are marked as applied.

EDIT:
<strike>How to force Django to use only one table `django_migrations`, but still apply the migrations into different databases?</strike>

How to apply the migrations in different databases so that no warnings are raised?

Comment: for other apps that are not 'my_app', allow_migrate is returning None. Maybe you want to do another check there? From what I understand from your router, 'my_app' uses the 'remote' database, and all other apps will use the 'default' database?

Comment: @cezar You ask for almost impossible. In order to have shared `django_migrations` table it will be required to differentiate between rows with migrations for `default` and `remote` db. This is pretty deep in the django internals.
I would even risk stating that it would require major rewrite of migration code.

Comment: @KamilNiski thank you for sharing your thoughts. I will reword the question.

Comment: [This issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23273) may be relevant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to the comments on my question I did some research and came up with the following findings.

Using multiple databases results in creating a table `django_migrations`when migrations are used. There is no option to record the migrations in only one table `django_migrations`, as the comment from [Kamil Niski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9820085/kamil-niski) explains. This is clear after reading the file [`django/db/migrations/recorder.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/migrations/recorder.py).

I will illustrate an example with a project `foo` and an app `bar` inside the project. The app `bar` has only one model `Baz`.

We create the project:

```
django-admin startproject foo
```

Now we have these contents inside the main project directory:

```
- foo
- manage.py
```

I have a habit to group all apps inside the project directory:

```
mkdir foo/bar
python manage.py bar foo/bar
```

In the file `foo/settings.py` we adjust the settings to use two different databases, for the purposes of this example we use `sqlite3`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db1.sqlite3'),
    },
    'remote': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db2.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Now we run the migrations:

```
python manage.py migrate --database=default
```

This runs all migrations, the part `--database=default` is optional, because if not specified Django uses the default database.

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
```

Django has applied all migrations to the default database:

```
1           contenttypes  0001_initial  2019-11-13 16:51:04.767382
2           auth          0001_initial  2019-11-13 16:51:04.792245
3           admin         0001_initial  2019-11-13 16:51:04.827454
4           admin         0002_logentr  2019-11-13 16:51:04.846627
5           admin         0003_logentr  2019-11-13 16:51:04.864458
6           contenttypes  0002_remove_  2019-11-13 16:51:04.892220
7           auth          0002_alter_p  2019-11-13 16:51:04.906449
8           auth          0003_alter_u  2019-11-13 16:51:04.923902
9           auth          0004_alter_u  2019-11-13 16:51:04.941707
10          auth          0005_alter_u  2019-11-13 16:51:04.958371
11          auth          0006_require  2019-11-13 16:51:04.965527
12          auth          0007_alter_v  2019-11-13 16:51:04.981532
13          auth          0008_alter_u  2019-11-13 16:51:05.004149
14          auth          0009_alter_u  2019-11-13 16:51:05.019705
15          auth          0010_alter_g  2019-11-13 16:51:05.037023
16          auth          0011_update_  2019-11-13 16:51:05.054449
17          sessions      0001_initial  2019-11-13 16:51:05.063868
```

Now we create the model `Baz`:

*`models.py`*:

```
from django.db import models

class Baz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

register the app `bar` into `INSTALLED_APPS` (`foo/settings.py`) and create the migrations:

```
python manage.py makemigrations bar
```

Before we run the migrations we create `routers.py` inside the `bar` app:

```
class BarRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'bar':
            return 'remote'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'bar':
            return 'remote'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label == 'bar':
            return db == 'remote'
        if db == 'remote':
            return False
        return None
```

and register it in `foo/settings.py`:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['foo.bar.routers.BarRouter']
```

Now the naive approach would be to run the migrations for `bar` into the `remote` database:

```
python manage.py migrate bar --database=remote
```

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: bar
Running migrations:
  Applying bar.0001_initial... OK
```

The migrations has been applied to the `remote` database:

```
1           bar         0001_initial  2019-11-13 17:32:39.701784
```

When we run:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

the following warning will be raised:

> You have 1 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly
>   until you apply the migrations for app(s): bar.
>   Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

Everything seems to work fine though. However it isn't satisfying having this warning.

The proper way would be to run all migrations for each database as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35614973/3848833).

It would look like this:

```
python manage.py migrate --database=default
python manage.py migrate --database=remote
```

and after creating the migrations for `bar`:

```
python manage.py migrate bar --database=default
python manage.py migrate bar --database=remote
```

The router will take care that the table `bar_baz` is created only in the `remote` database, but Django will mark the migrations as applied in both databases. Also the tables for `auth`, `admin`, `sessions`, etc. will be created only in the `default` database, as specified in `routers.py`. The table `django_migrations` in the `remote` database will have records for these migrations too.

It is a long reading, but I hope it sheds some light on this, in my opinion, not thoroughly explained issue in the official [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/#synchronizing-your-databases).