# How can we automate migrations for multiple database in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I am working with mult-tenant setup in django.I have **multiple databases** for which I am looking for a way to run a migration across all the databases linked in my settings.py file in one go.

Currently, I have to do

```
python manage.py migrate --database=db_name
```

for all the databases one by one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django migrations with multiple databases with multiple apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59057370/django-migrations-with-multiple-databases-with-multiple-apps)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion...i have implemented the same logic last month !!